# iOS Crashlytics raw unprocessed crash log

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

Is it possible in Crashlytics to download raw, unprocessed crash/non-fatals iOS logs? By raw I mean logs that have not yet been symbolicated . 
I'm having some trouble with Bitcode enabled builds and all my symbols are marked as `hidden`. I have the necessary dSYMs and I'd really like to try to symbolicate some crashes locally, but I wasn't able to find such possibility anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to download the raw crash logs. If this is an Ad Hoc distribution, disable "Rebuild from Bitcode" (which is enabled by default on XCode 9 now), and that should remove the `hidden` symbols.